# Icon Font No Longer Displaying Character on WordPress Site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-face

On my WordPress site the icons that were rendered with fonts are no longer displaying the icon. Instead they are displayed as a little square.

I see this in 2 locations on my site. The sidebar that displays social icons. And the 3 lined menu icon when the browser window is sized down to the mobile layout.

On Mac OS X I see the error on Firefox 31, and Chrome 37. But it works correctly on Safari 7.

Here's the URL: www.ashton.me

Why is this happening?
What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

In WordPress Settings "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" both needed the www version of the URL and it cleared right up.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the Network tab in Chrome Inspector (or similar in other browsers) you will notice that your icon fonts are not loading correctly. Missing glyphs are displayed as a square, so that is what you are seeing. And different browsers use different font files (or may have the correct file in cache) so that is probably why it does work in Safari.

[image: screenshot Chrome Inspector]